# data frames with python api

Tags: python, dataframe

panda data tables
how do i get this json data into a python dataframe with pandas

{"api":{"results":1,"statistics":{"matchs":{"matchsPlayed":{"home":19,"away":19,"total":38},"wins":{"home":10,"away":9,"total":19},"draws":{"home":6,"away":3,"total":9},"loses":{"home":3,"away":7,"total":10}},"goals":{"goalsFor":{"home":33,"away":32,"total":65},"goalsAgainst":{"home":25,"away":29,"total":54}},"goalsAvg":{"goalsFor":{"home":"1.7","away":"1.7","total":"1.7"},"goalsAgainst":{"home":"1.3","away":"1.5","total":"1.4"}}}}}

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas.read_json()`. Refer to : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html